# Initializing a constant in a class

Tags: c++

I created a simple class for calculating the area of a rectangle.

```
class Rectangle
{
public:
    Rectangle();
    Rectangle(const double, const double);

    class Invalid { };

    double print_square();
private:
    const double length, width;
    inline bool check();
};
```

For width and length, I used constants, because they will not be modified in my class. In the constructor, I want to initialize them.

Why do I get an error in constructor body?

> Cannot assign to non-static data member 'length' with const-qualified
>   type 'const double'
>
> Constructor for 'Rectangle' must explicitly initialize the const
>   member 'length'

**Error:**

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(const double _length, const double _width)
{
    length = _length;
    width = _width;
    if (!check())
        throw Invalid();
}
```

**OK:**

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(const double _length, const double _width) : length(_length), width(_width)
{
    if (!check())
        throw Invalid();
}
```

I quite like the second option, but for a more convenient readability I do not want to write all the initialized variables in one line.

***Is there a way to initialize a constant in the body of the constructor?***

Comment: I don't see why you can't put them on a different line. C++ isn't really space sensitive.

Comment: Try using the initializer list

Comment: You're getting an error because you're trying to assign to a constant variable. There's a difference between assignment and initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.

This is because in your first example, since there is nothing in the initializer list, `length` and `width` will be default constructed, and *then*, in the body of the constructor, assigned the needed values `_length` and `_width`, which fails because they are `const`and already initalized.

In your second example, both variables are initialized without being default constructed. This approach constructs the `const` variables directly with the needed values, in one step.

Note that approach 2 uses only one step instead of two, so it is more efficient than what you want to do in approach 1. Because of that, it is generally good practice (even for non-`const` variables) to go with approach 2 whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to initialize a constant in the body of the constructor?

No.

You must use the initializer list (your second solution):

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(const double _length, const double _width) : 
  length(_length), 
  width(_width)
{
    if (!check())
        throw Invalid();
}
```

As already stated in a comment, you can put each variable initialization on a separate line